# Calculate average among JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, algorithm

I need to calculate the average of all attribute of an json array.
This is the solution I propose, it works, but I think there are more elegant way to reach the same result.

```js
const measures = ['g1','g2','g3'];
const res = [{g1: 1, g2: 3, g3: 5}, {g1: 2, g2: 4, g3: 6}, {g1: 3, g2: 5, g3: 7}]
const data = { g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0 };
for (let i = 0; i < measures.length; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < res.length; j += 1) {
    data[measures[i]] += res[j][measures[i]];
  }
  data[measures[i]] /= res.length;
}
console.log(data)
```

runnable example:
https://repl.it/repls/SilverFlippantKiwi

I appreciate solutions which include some libraries like Lodash

Comment: This would be better suited for code-review.

Comment: you mean to use the tag code-review?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tinytanks Did you read the tag description for [tag:code-review]? If you decide to migrate this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), make sure you've read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

## Explanation

1. Convert your data to `{key: [value1, value2, ...], key2: [values]}`
2. Then convert the values of this object to the mean

## Code

```js
const measures = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3'];
const res = [{
  g1: 1,
  g2: 3,
  g3: 5
}, {
  g1: 2,
  g2: 4,
  g3: 6
}, {
  g1: 3,
  g2: 5,
  g3: 7
}]

let a = 
_.mapValues(                    // convert the list of numbers to the mean (step 2)
    _.mergeWith(                // group the values by key (step 1)
                {},                 // start with an empty object
                ...res,             // pass each element in your original array (res) as an argument
                (objValue, srcValue) => // add each element with the right key to an array for that key
                  _.isArray(objValue) ? objValue.concat(srcValue) : [srcValue]),
    _.mean);

 console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```